# How to include upstream file in Debian package?

Tags: debian, packages, dpkg

My package is complex but I've built a minimal example so that you can easily understand:

```
.
├── test-package
│   └── debian
│       ├── changelog
│       ├── compat
│       ├── control
│       ├── rules
│       └── source
│           └── format
├── test-package_0.1.0.orig
│   └── test_file
└── test-package_0.1.0.orig.tar.gz
```

The `debian/source/format` file contains `3.0 (quilt)`, which is why the upstream tarball is `test-package_0.1.0.orig.tar.gz`.  That tarball contains `test_file`.

The `debian/rules` file contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@
```

If I change to the `test-package` directory and run `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`, I get the following warning and my package won't have the file from upstream:

```
dpkg-source: warning: ignoring deletion of file test_file, use --include-removal to override
```

I read about `dh_install` and then added a `debian/test-package.install` file with the following content:

```
test_file opt/test-package/test_file
```

But then I get an error:

```
dh_install: Cannot find (any matches for) "test_file" (tried in "." and "debian/tmp")
dh_install: test-package missing files: test_file
dh_install: missing files, aborting
```

Where is `test_file` to be found?  Perhaps this is the wrong method.  What should I try instead in that case? Can I avoid modifying the upstream package, which doesn't have a makefile or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upstream tarball `test-package_0.1.0.orig.tar.gz` is indeed needed where it is.  However, `dpkg-buildpackage` also expects this upstream tarball to be decompressed in `test-package` besides the `debian` directory.  Then it can build the binary package and distinguish the Debian overlay from upstream content.

Correct layout:

```
.
├── test-package
│   ├── debian
│   │   ├── changelog
│   │   ├── compat
│   │   ├── control
│   │   ├── rules
│   │   ├── source
│   │   │    └── format
│   │   └── test-package.install
│   └── test_file
└── test-package_0.1.0.orig.tar.gz
```